# Avoiding break in a while loop

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

The task: in an ascending float array sum the values within a certain range.
The code below solves the problem using `break` twice, first time within a necessary amendment of `array.binary_search_rightmost` and second in the main loop.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © moebius1977

//@version=5
indicator("My script")

//----------- binary_search_rightmost_first() -----------{
// @function The difference with binary_search_leftmost is that for, e.g., (2,5,5,5,8) this search for 5 returns index 1, whereas the built-in method returns index 3.
method binary_search_rightmost_first(float[] this, float _val) =>
    _i = this.binary_search_rightmost(_val)
    while _i > 0 // even though _i happens to be == this.size() if _val is out of array's range, we only use get(_i-1) 
        if this.get(_i-1) == _val
            _i -=1
        else    
            break 
            _i
    _i 
// END OF binary_search_rightmost_first() }


arAscFloat = array.from(1., 1, 3, 3, 3, 6)

// calc sum of elements between 3 and 8 inclusive
minF = input.float(3, "minF") 
maxF = input.float(8, "maxF") 

i = arAscFloat.binary_search_rightmost_first(minF)
sum = 0. 
while i < arAscFloat.size()
    if arAscFloat.get(i) < maxF 
        sum += arAscFloat.get(i)
    else
        break
    i+=1

plot(sum)
```

Can this be written more elegantly, without using `break`?

(I could override method `get()` as follows of course:

```
method get(float[] ar, int i) => 
    if i >= 0 and i < ar.size()
        ar.get(i)
    else
        na
```

but that makes frequently used `get()` less efficient, not good.